# Dynamic PHP that creates navbar from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, list, dynamic, navbar

I am trying to figure out where I went wrong with my code.
I built my navbar with php in the unordered list of the navbar to retrieve the menu elements from an SQL table called "menu" from a database called "shop", with no avail.
I even have a print_r in place, only to show me that my resource is working, but for some reason the whole code isn't creating the menu items as written.

This is the code:

```
    <?php 
$menu = [];
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('shop');

$result=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $menu[] = $row;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
$error= print_r($menu);
$error = '' ;
 echo '</pre>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link href="_CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="site-wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                    <?php if(count($menu) >0) : ?>
                    <?php foreach ($menu as $row) : ?>
                    <li><a href="#"><?php $row = ['link']; ?></a></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
                </div>       
               <div class="member">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../login.php"></a>Login</li>
                        <li><a href="../Register.php"></a>Register</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
               </div>
        </div>
```

The result unfortunately looks like this:
[image]

Comment: There's nothing in your inline PHP (inside the list) that echos anything... Also you don't need to check the count of the array first; foreach will do the right thing with an empty array.

Comment: You shouldn't use the mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and are being remvoed http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
<?php $row = ['link']; ?>
```

It should probably be this:

```
<?php echo $row['link']; ?>
```

Maybe you got confused trying to do this:

```
<?= $row['link']?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mistake 1 :**

You have used

`$row = ['link'];`

Where you will get this error `Notice: Array to string conversion in ..`

So you need to have `$row['link'];`

**Mistake 2 :**

You need to output the content using `echo`

`<li><a href="#"><?php echo $row['link']; ?></a></li>`

**Warning :** Don't use `mysql_*` functions as it is [depreciated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) instead use mysqli or PDO for safer Operations !

Comment: First, thanks for the answer Sulthan! Second, I totally missed that, I wanted to use <?= ... would that been ok too?

Comment: @erezT You're welcome. Yes you can use it ! Here's the output sample you will be getting http://s13.postimg.org/xr693pedz/image.png

Comment: You shall use this `<li><a href="#"><?= $row['link']; ?></a></li>` to achieve the one that i have given in the screenshot in above link ;)